# General memoization procedure in Scheme

Tags: scheme, memoization, sicp, r5rs

I am trying to create a general memoization procedure in Scheme. This is what I have so far (it's almost completely the same as excercise 3.27 in the SICP book):

```
(define (memo proc)
  (let ((table (make-table)))
    (lambda (args)
      (let ((prev (lookup args table)))
        (or prev
            (let ((result (proc args)))
              (insert! args result table)
              result))))))
```

(The 'make-table', 'insert!' and 'lookup' procedures are defined in the SICP book)

If i call this method with a procedure that only takes one argument, it works just fine. What I can't figure out how to do is get it to work with a procedure that takes 0 or several arguments.

I found this link: http://community.schemewiki.org/?memoization , but I still can't get it to work. The procedure in the link uses apply values and call-with-values, and even though I got a rough idea on how they work, I can't seem to integrate it with my procedure.

```
 (define (mem2 proc)
   (let ((table (make-table)))
        (lambda args
          (let ((prev (lookup args table)))
            (or prev
                (call-with-values
                 (lambda () (apply proc args))
                 (lambda (result)
                   (insert! args result table)
                   result)))))))
```

This is my try on the procedure from the link, using a list. It's almost working, but if I have a procedure that takes several arguments, it will compute it several times. Let's say I pass a random procedure the arguments 1 2 3 4. It will save 1 2 3 4 in the table, but not the given results for 1, 2, 3 and 4 seperately. I guess my error is where I do the lookup, since I pass the whole list at once.

EDIT: added testprocedure that mem2 does not work correctly with.

```
(define (add . args)
  (display "computing add of ")
  (display args) (newline)
  (if (null? args)
      0
      (+ (car args) (apply add (cdr args)))))
```

It will save in the lookup table the whole 'args'. So if I have:

> (define add (mem2 add))
>
> (add 2 3 4)
>
> computing add of (2 3 4)
>
> computing add of (3 4)
>
> computing add of (4)
>
> 9
>
> (add 3)
>
> computing add of (3)

Comment: ellipsis-snip% suggets you are using Racket. Are you interested in a solution using Racket hash tables, or are you sticking to r5rs?

Comment: I want to stick to using r5rs and lists :) I edited my answer, I changed a couple of things in the procedure, but it still doesn't work exactly as I want it to...

Comment: Is the input arguments of a particular type?

Comment: I have a test procedure that takes arbitrary many numbers as argument, which I use with the mem2 procedure.

Comment: I tried again with 'apply values' to the procedure mem2 above. I get an error on the last call of the calculation: expected mpair, given 1 (f.ex). So if I try to use mem2 with fib, and I call fib with 4 for example, it will compute 4, 3, 2, and then get the mpair error with 1.

Comment: Your memoized procedure recurses against the unmemoized version so the subresults would not be memoized. However you can do this by using the memoized version when you recurse. eg. `(define mproc (mem2 (lambda args (if (null? args) 0 (+ (car args) (apply mproc (cdr args)))))))` This can be invisible in a `define-memo` syntax-rules macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (make-table)
  (vector '()))

(define (insert! key val t)
  (vector-set! t 0 (cons (cons key val) (vector-ref t 0))))

(define (lookup key t)
  (let ([result (assoc key (vector-ref t 0))])
    (and result (cdr result))))

(define (mem2 proc)
  (let ((table (make-table)))
    (lambda args
      (let ((prev (lookup args table)))
        (or prev
            (let ([result (apply proc args)])
              (insert! args result table)
              result))))))

(define (plus x y)
  (display (list "Computing sum of: " x y))
  (newline)
  (+ 1 2))

(define memo-plus (mem2 plus))

(memo-plus 1 2)
(memo-plus 1 2)
```

Output:

```
(Computing sum of:  1 2)
3
3
```

Adding:

```
(define (add . args)
  (display "computing add of ")
  (display args) (newline)
  (if (null? args)
      0
      (+ (car args) (apply add (cdr args)))))

(define memo-add (mem2 add))

(memo-add 1 2 3 4)
(memo-add 1 2 3 4)
```

Gives the output:

```
computing add of (1 2 3 4)
computing add of (2 3 4)
computing add of (3 4)
computing add of (4)
computing add of ()
10
10
```

Since nothing was printed before the last 10, the example
show that the result was memoized.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think this code will generate the same problem as mine (see what I have written under mem2 above). I

Comment: Make an example, so we can try it.

Comment: Added a procedure 'add' and a run example to show what I mean